# Load php variable in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

im newbie

how to load variable php in javascript?

this is my script (popup.php)

```
<?php $id_user = $this->session->userdata('id'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">rules: {
        user: {
  required: true,
  number: true,
  range: [1, 8]
}  <script>
```

example variable.

`$id_user = 10;`

how to input a `id_user` to `range: [1,8]`

so the range output is `range: [1,10]`

sory for my bad english

thank you so much

BR

Puja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var $uid = <?php echo json_encode($this->session->userdata('id')); ?>;
rules: {
  user: {
  required: true,
  number: true,
  range: [1, $uid]
} 
 <script>
```

Why `json_encode`? It turns the value you pass to it into valid JSON - quotes the strings, escapes quotes and other special chars, etc. Without it, you're basically going to break whenever your echoed variable contains something other than a simple alphanumeric string.

Comment: You really should [`json_encode`](http://us.php.net/json_encode) the value instead of just surrounding it with single quotes.

Comment: @DCoder i'm not very well versed in php if you see any room for edit in the anwer plz feel free to edit...

Comment: i try with or without 'json_encode' its work for me. thank you so much @DCoder,@3nigma

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `echo` in php to create variables in javascript. personally I would handle this situation like this:

```
<?php echo "<script>var user_id = ".$this->session->userdata('id').";</script>"; ?>
<script>
  rules: {
    user: {
    required: true,
    number: true,
    range: [1, user_id]
   }
  }  
</script>
```