# PHP variable inside AJAX data string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request, referenceerror

I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: bierta (or whatever the URL var is) is not defined` when I run the AJAX call below. How can I fix this?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  async: false,
  url: "get-single-marker.php",
  data: "slug="+<?php echo $_GET['gt']; ?>,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(res) {
    data = res;
  }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load php variable in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708974/load-php-variable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
data: "slug=<?php echo $_GET['gt']; ?>,
```

or

`data:{slug:"<?php echo $_GET['gt']; ?>"},`

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
data: "slug="+<?php echo json_encode($_GET['gt']); ?>,
```

or

```
data: "slug=<?php echo $_GET['gt']; ?>",
```

or grab the `gt` from the query using JavaScript.

View source to see why your version doesn't work.

Regardless of the method you use, you need to make sure you properly validate/escape the input. `$_GET` is untrusted stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a variable to the element here, and that is why it give you an error.

Try Following Code.

```
data: "slug=<?php echo $_GET['gt']; ?>",
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

i hope this may work

```
data: { slug : <?php echo $_GET['gt']; ?> }  ,
```

quotes are not necessary