# YouTube IFrame API, Load PHP Data AND Add Player Control Function

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, youtube-api, media

I have a database driven YouTube video player, where video codes are loaded from a table and played back in a `<div>`. But I have 2 problems:

**1)** How do I load in the video codes from my php code into the Javascript?

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$code_sql = "SELECT * FROM music_codes WHERE id = '$url_id'";
$code_res = mysqli_query($con, $code_sql);
while($code = mysqli_fetch_assoc($code_res)){

    $code_1 = $code["one"];
    $code_2 = $code["two"];
    $code_3 = $code["three"];
    $code_4 = $code["four"];
    $code_5 = $code["five"];
    $code_6 = $code["six"];
    $code_7 = $code["seven"];
    $code_8 = $code["eight"];

};
?>
```

And Javascript where I need to display the php:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="//www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>
    /**
     * Put your video IDs in this array
     */
    var videoIDs = [
        ' ** $code_1 ** ', // PHP Code Display
        ' ** $code_2 ** ', // PHP Code Display
        etc,
        etc
    ];

    var player, currentVideoId = 0;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '350',
            width: '425',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            currentVideoId++;
            if (currentVideoId < videoIDs.length) {
                player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**2)** How do I add better control for users to skip videos? At the moment it plays each video one after the other, but there is no way of letting them click next or previous. This is very much needed for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a function to change currentVideoId:

```
function next(){
    currentVideoId++;
    if (currentVideoId < videoIDs.length) {
            player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
    }
}

function prev(){
    currentVideoId--;
    if (currentVideoId >= 0) {
            player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
    }
    else currentVideoId = 0;
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="button" value=""Next" onclick="next()" />
<input type="button" value=""Previous" onclick="prev()" />
```

And the same for previous.

Comment: And can this simply go beneath `function onPlayerStateChange(event)`?

Comment: The main part of `function onPlayerStateChange(event)` is `player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);` that the next() function has it.

Comment: the `function onPlayerStateChange(event)` is only for changing the vidoe **when it ended**. But you do not want it end.

Comment: I've added it to the bottom of my Javascript and the `next` function works perfectly. I must have made a mistake with `previous` as I get an error message inside the video player. Which part of the code do I have to change? I just changed `<` to `>`

Comment: I added the prev fundtion.

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly. I'll give it an accept, but would you happen to know the answer to the first part of my question... How to load up the PHP variable in the Javascript?

Comment: Shame for me! I do not know PHP. But you can read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708974/load-php-variable-in-javascript. Thanks for accept.

Comment: Thanks again. It doesn't completely work for the code I have, but it gives me something to work with.